# Group similar object values in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have initial data like this :

```
[
    {
        "ru":"R401","area":"RFCC","unit":"OFFSITE","tot":1
    }, {
        "ru":"R401","area":"RFCC","unit":"OFFSITE","tot":1
    }, {
        "ru":"R401","area":"RFCC","unit":"OFFSITE","tot":1
    }, {
        "ru":"R401","area":"RFCC","unit":"RCU","tot":1
    }
]
```

I want to push array in object if some keys are same, and the result become like this :

```
    [
        {
            "ru":"R401",
            "tot":[1, 1, 1, 1],
            "unit":["OFFSITE","OFFSITE","OFFSITE","RCU"]
        }
    ]
```

Then, I want to group the objects 'tot' and 'unit' then push it into a new array, if the Corresponding values of keys 'tot' and 'unit' are same, but my logic is bad.

And I want the output to be like this :

```
[
    {
        "ru":"R401",
        "tot":[1, 1],
        "unit":["OFFSITE","RCU"]
    }
]
```

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Comment: you can try `Set` for unit.

Comment: why `[1, 1]` and not `[1]`?

Comment: Why are there 2 `1`s in `tot` if they're being grouped?

Comment: What is your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: do you have an array with different `ru` values?

Comment: No research effort or prior trials shown here.

Comment: Hi, please check my edited question, maybe you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't morph your questions into different questions, particularly if that invalidates the answers given by those who took time to help you and makes that effort less useful to future readers.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the corresponding values of both array, assuming they have the same length.

```js
var object = { ru: "R401", tot: [1, 1, 1, 1], unit: ["OFFSITE", "OFFSITE", "OFFSITE", "RCU"] },
    unique = new Set,
    i = object.tot.length, 
    json;
    
while (i--) {
    json = JSON.stringify([object.tot[i], object.unit[i]]);
    if (unique.has(json)) {
        object.tot.splice(i, 1);
        object.unit.splice(i, 1);
        continue;
    }
    unique.add(json);
}

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score -1):

Right, using Set is the right choice.

I would make it more generic:

```js
const source = [
{
    "ru":"R401",
    "tot":[1, 1, 1, 1],
    "unit":["OFFSITE","OFFSITE","OFFSITE","RCU"]
}];

source.map(el => {
    Object.entries(el).forEach( en => {
        if(Array.isArray(el[en[0]]))
            el[en[0]] = Array.from(new Set(el[en[0]]));
    });
});

console.log(source);
```

Is that what you need?